# Rails: NameError with lib module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my device model I try to call a class method on a lib class, but on production I get a

`NameError (uninitialized constant Device::Push):`

It works on develoment, though.

But I don't call a Device::Push class. Instead that's what I'm doing in my Device model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_update :send_notifications
  ...
  def send_notifications
    Push::NotificationFactory.send(device: self) if (self.push_token_changed? && ! self.push_token.nil?)
  end
end
```

And in lib/push/notification_factory.rb the following class should be called:

```
module Push
  class NotificationFactory
    def self.send(device: )
      n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
      n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name(Rails.configuration.x.app['push']['app_name'])
      n.device_token = device.push_token
      n.alert = 'Welcome to PrizeArena!'
      n.save!
    end
  end
end
```

That's the error message I get:

```
2016-02-28T13:40:51.407542+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Device::Push):
2016-02-28T13:40:51.407543+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/device.rb:77:in `send_notifications'
2016-02-28T13:40:51.407544+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:44:in `update'
```

Would be great if somebody could point out where the NameError is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem why it worked on development but not on production.

I was adding lib to the auto_load path, but needed to add it to the eager_load_path.

You need to add

`config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

to application.rb

The problem was only happening on production, not on development, because on production Rails eager_loads the environment by default.

More information here: 
http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/

Answer (score 0):

> NameError (uninitialized constant Device::Push)

You need to use `include` to embed a `module` in a `class`.

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Push
  ...
  after_update :send_notifications
  ...
  def send_notifications
    Push::NotificationFactory.send(device: self) if (self.push_token_changed? && ! self.push_token.nil?)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out that it's a production environment problem and due to Rails eager_loading the env in production.